# Fragment is not showing from the beginning | Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment

When I come to this Fragment it is not showing from the beginning .It is showing from somewhere else..

[image: pic]

I want it should start showing from the beginning ..
like number ..

1,2,3..9

Above image I was downloaded from the some website just to easily explain my question (this image not related to below code)

Below is my fragment code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ProgramOutcomesFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="ABOUT DEPARTMENT"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            style="@style/welcom_text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/college_color_dark"
                android:layout_height="100px">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/GreenText"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="VISION"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </TextView>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:id="@+id/deptvision"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/college_color_dark"
                android:layout_height="100px">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/GreenText"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="MISSION"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </TextView>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:id="@+id/deptmission"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>





        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/college_color_dark"
                android:layout_height="100px">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/GreenText"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="DEPARTMENT PROFILE"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </TextView>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:id="@+id/deptprofile"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/college_color_dark"
                android:layout_height="100px">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/GreenText"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="PRORAMME EDUCATIONAL OBJECTIVES(PEO)"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </TextView>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:id="@+id/deptpeo"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>






        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/college_color_dark"
                android:layout_height="100px">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/GreenText"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="PROGRAMME OUTCOMES(PO)"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </TextView>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:id="@+id/deptpo"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/college_color_dark"
                android:layout_height="100px">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/GreenText"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="PROGRAMME SPECIFIC OUTCOMES (PSO"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </TextView>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/deptpso"
                android:justificationMode="inter_word"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Java code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ProgramOutcomesFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView deptvison,deptmission,deptprofile,deptpeo,deptpo,deptpso;

    public ProgramOutcomesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_program_outcomes, container, false);

        deptvison = view.findViewById(R.id.deptvision);
        deptmission = view.findViewById(R.id.deptmission);
        deptprofile = view.findViewById(R.id.deptprofile);
        deptpeo = view.findViewById(R.id.deptpeo);
        deptpso = view.findViewById(R.id.deptpso);
        deptpo = view.findViewById(R.id.deptpo);

        String branch = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this.getContext()).getBranch();

        switch(branch){

            case "cse":
                deptvison.setText(this.getString(R.string.csevision));
                deptmission.setText(this.getString(R.string.csemission));
                deptprofile.setText(this.getString(R.string.cseprofile));
                deptpso.setText(this.getString(R.string.csepso));
                deptpo.setText(this.getString(R.string.csepo));
                deptpeo.setText(this.getString(R.string.csepeo));
            break;

            case "ise":
                deptvison.setText(this.getString(R.string.isevision));
                deptmission.setText(this.getString(R.string.isemission));
                deptprofile.setText(this.getString(R.string.iseprofile));
                deptpso.setText(this.getString(R.string.isepso));
                deptpo.setText(this.getString(R.string.csepo));
                deptpeo.setText(this.getString(R.string.isepeo));
                break;

            case "ece":
                deptvison.setText(this.getString(R.string.ecvision));
                deptmission.setText(this.getString(R.string.ecmission));
                deptprofile.setText(this.getString(R.string.ecprofile));
                deptpso.setText(this.getString(R.string.ecpso));
                deptpo.setText(this.getString(R.string.csepo));
                deptpeo.setText(this.getString(R.string.ecpeo));
                break;
            case "me":
                deptvison.setText(this.getString(R.string.mevision));
                deptmission.setText(this.getString(R.string.memission));
                deptprofile.setText(this.getString(R.string.meprofile));
                deptpso.setText(this.getString(R.string.mepso));
                deptpo.setText(this.getString(R.string.csepo));
                deptpeo.setText(this.getString(R.string.mepeo));
                break;

            case "ee":
                deptvison.setText(this.getString(R.string.eevision));
                deptmission.setText(this.getString(R.string.eemission));
                deptprofile.setText(this.getString(R.string.eeprofile));
                deptpso.setText(this.getString(R.string.eepso));
                deptpo.setText(this.getString(R.string.csepo));
                deptpeo.setText(this.getString(R.string.eepeo));
                break;

            default:
                deptvison.setText(this.getString(R.string.csevision));
                deptmission.setText(this.getString(R.string.csemission));
                deptprofile.setText(this.getString(R.string.cseprofile));
                deptpso.setText(this.getString(R.string.csepso));
                deptpo.setText(this.getString(R.string.csepo));
                deptpeo.setText(this.getString(R.string.csepeo));
        }



        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code, always! is this `ListView` or `RecyclerView`? I bet this is a problem with requesting focus by last/all list item, scrolling whole layout to bottom

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't used ScrollView.
Use ScrollView inside the FrameLayout
and then a RelativeLayout/LinearLayout/ConstraintLayout inside the ScrollView.

I hope I understood your question correctly.
Thank You
Hope it works

Comment: root/first of all views in XML is `ScrollView` in fact...

Answer (score 0):

your current approach is very bad, you should switch to `RecyclerView` and some adapter implementation - some doc in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) and many tutorials in Internet. if you REALLY want to prevent undesired behavior (autoscroll to bottom) then you may try [THIS](http://www.java2s.com/example/android/user-interface/scrollview-disable-auto-scroll-to-bottom.html) solution - it looks like one of your views (maybe all) is requesting focus, which makes `ScrollView` auto-scroll to it at the beginning. but still this should be list with items (as they are nearly exacly same), not scroll with one layout with multiple childs, so long that it needs scrolling